# How to synchronize list changes over network in Python

Tags: python, networking, server, synchronization

I am developing a little group management system where there are two different types of servers. The "client server" which can join and leave groups on the "management server".

There are multiple management servers in a multicast group. So the client servers send the join and leave requests to this multicast group. Due to the fact that IPv6 multicast is not reliable, there is the possibility that some management servers do not receive the requests. So their list óf memberships is not up to date.

So I need a function that I can use to synchronize lists whenever they change. There are three types of changes:

- client server leaves group
- client server joins group
- client server updates its complete list of memberships (so the management server replaces its list)

I thought of creating a log list on each management server that logs the recent changes (maybe of the last 60 seconds). If a server notices a change it informs the other management servers about the change and sends the time with this information. If the receiver has a more recent change it ignores the information of the sender. If not, it updates its list.

But is this the best way to do this? Are there special patterns for such things? Or maybe even a python framework?

Comment: So any change on  any management server has to be reflected on all the servers yes?

Comment: I would use something like spanning tree, have a root that all servers send updates to after changes then send out a revision number every so often, if the revision number is greater than the current sync the changes.

Comment: Yes, on all management servers. Assume we have two management servers A and B. A client server registers via a multicast to the group where A and B are members. But due to network problems only A receives the register request. So B has an invalid view on the list of groups the client server is member in. To solve this, after every register process every management server syncs the new list with all other management servers.

Comment: So in the end, what I want, is that every management server has always (except small delays) the same view on the list. The main reason why I need this is that the management servers are chosen by a loadbalancer and the user should always get the same results independent of which management server handles the user request

Comment: Hi, I cannot use another "master server" for the synchronisation as this server would be the new bottleneck. And what if this server crashes? One of the main goals of my application is to be as robust as possible. So we have multiple management servers. One management server can replace another if it crashes

Comment: As far as crashing goes you could  use a primary and secondary, if the root crashes and no packet is received within the time period then fail over to the secondary.  I will have a think about it and see if anything comes to mind but essentially if you don't want to use a root and have one server keep track of changes then the alternative is going to be something similar to what you have suggested in your question. I do think keeping logs and having all servers updating each other could get messy though.

Comment: [PubSub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/) may solve? or 0mq, amqp?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). It's useful for exactly the scenario you're talking about where you want events synchronized between multiple nodes. It'll abstract away most of the networking layer for you too, so you can focus on getting work done instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I don't see how this could help me. Another problem is that I have to use a big framework of my university for the registration / deregistration of the clients which already handles all of the nework stuff. So the only problem is how to sync the changes and not how to do the communication. The communication already works :)